# How to display images from object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

How to display image from object?
I was trying to copy relative path, but it's not working for me. Output on browser:

> ./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png

data.json

```
"image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
```

comment.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../../data.json';

const Comment = () => {
  const mapData = Object.values(data.comments).map((value) => (
    <div key={value.id}>
      <div>
        <img src={value.user.image.png} alt={value.user.image.png} />
        {value.content}
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  return <>{mapData}</>;
};

export default Comment;
```

Link to repository: https://github.com/xflameyoke/interactive-comment-section-app

Comment: You just need to move your images to the [`public`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system) directory in your source code repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that way the images are out of scope for `data.json` while rendering.

You must move your images folder `images/avatars/` to the root of the `/public` folder in your project.

Meanwhile in `data.json`, modify the locations for each image, as if it (`data.json`) were inside the `/public` folder i.e. `"png": "/images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png"` and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

To add to jsecksn's answer, usually you would import images and the like at the top of your file like [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files). This ensures that when your project is built, webpack will copy the necessary resources etc.

Since your requirement does not allow for such an import, I believe that just copying the resources to the public folder and changing the url's from relative to absolute is the easiest approach.

Comment: Good information. However, the URLs don't need to be absolute: the content of the `public` folder is served at the location defined in the [`homepage`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) property in `package.json` (or the root of the published site/app if undefined). The URLs just need to be relative according to the current relationship of the URL where they're being rendered and that previously mentioned location.